# Best to emulate an edit text in a gridview of text fields?

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext

I am currently trying to program a game that will use an 8x8 grid. The grid will be populated with some numbers and some blank spaces. The user should be able to enter a number the empty boxes.

Currently I have a gridview that stores editText to display the numbers.
This however does not work because I am using an array adapter to populate the list initially, meaning the text is not updated even if the editText is effected.

My question is what is the best way to allow a user to edit the content of a gridview item?

Comment: Does everything need to be scrollable? If not you could just make a TableLayout

Comment: The opposite actually it needs to not be scrollable. I am currently forcing the grid to fit on screen else where in the code.

Comment: Also I need to have access to an adapter. After I get this data set working I will need to be added lots of different data sets to this grid.

Comment: You can manage the data for your TableLayout from your Activity (or a Manager/Utility class) just like you can an adapter. GridView has a lot of efficiency code built into it that makes it better for scrolling but a bit of a pain to work with in more static view. What is it from the adapter specifically that you are interested in?

Comment: I think the adapter will work better in this situation because every square will have and entry (1-64,or ""). Wouldn't working with a tablelayout require me to have 64 setText() calls? (one for each cell of the table) Or am I missing something?

Comment: I may be a bit confused at what you are trying to do. Is each field an edit text or is there a single edit text and it sets individual text views? There are a lot of ways to manage views. Are you trying to use getItem()?

Comment: Currently there is an 8x8 gridview that contains 64 editTexts. The value they will hold will may be different every time the program runs. And the user should be able to edit any editText that started with the value "". Hopefully that explains it a little better; sorry about the confusion.